# getting the order# from grid view to detail view

Tags: php, magento

I have created a module that list the orders that are available to be moderated in a grid in adminhtml.

I need to pass the orderId from the grid view to the detail view and I don't know how to do it.

Here is my `Grid.php`

```
{
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('moderationGrid');
    // This is the primary key of the database
    $this->setDefaultSort('increment_id');
    $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
}

protected function _prepareCollection() {
    $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns() {
    $this->addColumn('increment_id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order Number'),
        'align'     =>'center',
        'index'     => 'increment_id',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchase Date'),
        'align'     => 'center',
        'index'     => 'created_at',
        'type'      => 'datetime',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('action', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('moderation')->__('Action'),
        'align'     => 'center',
        'type'      => 'action',
        'getter'    => 'getId',
        'actions'   => array(
            array(
                'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Review'),
                'url'     => array('base'=>'*/adminhtml_moderation/view'),
                'field'   => 'increment_id'
            )
                ),
                'filter'    => false,
                'sortable'  => false,
                'index'     => 'stores',
                'is_system' => true,
    ));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

And here is my view `Form.php`

```
class Moderation_Block_Adminhtml_Moderation_View_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{    
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('moderation/form.phtml');
    }


    public function getOrder()
    {       
        $moderationId     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('increment_id');
        $order  = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement one more custom function in your grid.php (**hint:** this file named not by conventions, must be capital "G" - Grid.php):

```
public function getRowUrl($row)
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array(
        'id'=>$row->getId())
    );
}
```

That will give some other classes URL for yours every row.

For a reference look at `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid` line 320.

Comment: My Grid.php is capitalized, just a typo when posting. Thank you for your answer. I am both new to php and Magento. A double whammy.

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a session variable to hold it.

```
Mage::getModel('core/session')->setSomeVariable($id);
```

Then pull it.

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(Mage::getModel('core/session')->getSomeVariable();
```